# jQuery keypress not working as it needs to

Tags: jquery, keypress

What I want: When I press the letter "i" the toggle will do its work.

What it does: The toggle is working on every letter pressed on the keyboard

How to fix this?

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  e.which === 67;
  $('.metadata').slideToggle('.display-block'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed out the `if` condition, and `.display-block` isn't a valid parameter value for `slideToggle()`. Try this:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 67) {
    $('.metadata').slideToggle(); 
  }
});
```

Note that keyCode `67` is `B`. Your question states you want to use `i`, so in that case you'd need to change the value to `105`.

Comment: Nothing is happening when I change my code with yours

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/e20fp4b7/. Note that keycode 67 is `B` so you'll need to press SHIFT+B to see it work. If you want to use `i` then change `67` to `105`

Answer (score 0):

Use `document` instead of window. And you missed the IF (i think):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).keypress(function(e) {
     if ( e.which === 67 ) {
        $('.metadata').slideToggle('.display-block'); 
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Nothing is happening when I change my code with yours

Comment: Paste your entire code please. You're adding the script tag with the jQuery library?

Comment: Check it here! You should press Run in the top left and click on the bottom right frame to set the focus on it before pressing the C key. https://jsfiddle.net/s1o21gru/